# Is there a way to observe values of variables in each iteration?

Tags: c++

I'm new to learning how to code and I was wondering if there's a way to see values during each iteration of a loop. Here's a code I'm trying to understand. I know some of it but as it gets deeper, I get confused.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin; using std::endl;
using std::cout; using std::string;
int main()
{

    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";

    string name = "Jae";


    const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    const int pad = 1;
    const int rows = pad * 2 + 3;
    const string::size_type cols = greeting.size() + pad * 2 + 2;
    cout << endl;

        for (int r = 0; r != rows; ++r) {
            string::size_type c = 0;
            while (c != cols) {
                if (r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) {
                cout << greeting;
                c += greeting.size();
                } else {
                    if (r == 0 || r == rows - 1 ||
                        c == 0 || c == cols - 1)
                        cout << "*";
                else
                        cout << " ";
                        ++c;
                        }
                            }
                cout << endl;
                                        }
}
```

Comment: you mean a debugger ?

Comment: What variable you want to watch??

Comment: Either print them out so you can study the output at your leisure, or use a debugger: put a breakpoint at some place in the loop, add to watch expressions whatever interests you, and hit "run" each time to see what the next iteration does.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your code. If you debug, you can see values during each iteration of a loop

Comment: On visual studio use the F9 key to add a breakpoint at the line of code after you change the values of a variable that you want to look at. Then when you debug (Press F5) it will stop at that line each iteration. Hold the cursor over the variable and Visual Studio will show the value. Or you can look at the local variables window or add the variables to a watch window.

Comment: @user2826094 it's simple as **drescherjm** 's described. But i suggest you to read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

you can also watch this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1EQndVmlOc

Answer (score 0):

if r is your iterator, write inside the loop this line:

```
cout << r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.

[Mastering Debugging in Visual Studio 2010 - A Beginner's Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Simply you can execute your program line-by-line by pressing F10 key. And hovering mouse over variables shows their current value.